# Install New Software on Eclipse not working on Mac

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse classic x86_64 3.7 cocoa  on my Mac Intel Core 2 Duo with snow leopard 10.6.8

I have extracted and copied the eclipse directory to Applications folder. When run, 
I get following errors

```
System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.simpleRepository
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientBrowseFileTransferFactory$1.sendBrowseRequest(HttpClientBrowseFileTransferFactory.java:53)
Error while reading from repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/site.xml.
```

I have following java version

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
```

I have tried with eclipse classic 32 and 64 bit versions, with both i have the same problem .

I have also tried tweaking around priority of java version (32 or 64) under Java preferences.

Comment: What happens when you don't move it to be under the Applications folder?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Deleting /Library/Java/Extensions/log4j-1.2.15.jar resolved the issue.

Comment: Adding extra comments just incase someone lands here searching through the internets. This bug drove me crazy for the last one week. It was compounded by the fact that most users who complained were from Australia and only Mac Users were affected. The Australian users were just a coincidence. I deleted the log4j jar in extensions and also the sfl4j jars and voila! like a magic it worked! Cheers guys

Comment: omg, what a lifesaver I spent 7 hours trying to debug this, initially I thought it must been new java version I installed, I tried a 100 different workarounds.  Finally this, this extension was installed when I had to install the Australian Businesses Auskey software

Comment: The Australia users might not be a coincidence. The Australian Tax Office (ATO) uses a servlet based security called AUSKey, which appears to install SL4J, Log4j and some XML libraries in the /Library/Java/Extensions directory. This interferes with many other applications. The list of files I moved out are: jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jsr173_1.0_api.jar, log4j-1.2.15.jar, slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar As I still use AUSKey, I need to maintain these, and move them in and out of the Extensions directory to let me use it.

Comment: thanks. No thanks to ATO, which was the problem (the log4j-1.2.15.jar). I will access the tax agents' portal via a windows virtual machine.

Comment: Fixed for me too.  Yes, I had AUSKey installed on the affected Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using ubuntu instead and had this problem, just go

`cd /usr/java/packages/lib/ext/

sudo rm log4j-1.2.15.jar

sudo rm slf4j-*`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and had nothing under /Library/Java/Extensions
You can notice that Eclipse reports: "The value will be overwritten using values from the preferences". So what you can do - visit Preferences > Network Connections and under 'Proxy Bypass' add Host: *
This has resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I set this to solve the problem:
http.sslVerify false in the egit config file.

Comment: How does a git config setting (a very dangerous one at that - it breaks half of the benefits of SSL) affect the Eclipse plugin installer? The two would seem to be completely unrelated.

Comment: @stwalkerster You are right. That certainly seems to warrant a downvote (suggesting that people do something that would them much less secure, and that doesn't seem to have a bearing on the original question)